# calling a function inside a parent by detecting a call in the child in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to call a function inside a dropdown on clicking on a children which is a datepicker library

```
  <DropdownParent >
                <DatePicker
                    selectsStart
                    showYearDropdown
                    showMonthDropdown
                    endDate={endDate}
                    selected={startDate}
                    scrollableYearDropdown
                    dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                    startDate={startDate}
                    yearDropdownItemNumber={10}
                    onChange={(date) => handleChange({ startDateObj: date })}
                    placeholderText={placeholderStart}
                    inline
                    locale="en-gb"
                />
            </DropdownDefaultAtom>
```

in DropdownParent there is a toggle function which i need to call when this child function handleChange is called and I tried callback and other method but since its a library i am confused on hoe to detect the change and pass it in parent to invoke parent function

Comment: can you add ```childFunction```?

Comment: Also, it will be helpful if you can clarify which component is a library and which is not - what can you edit, and what you can't exactly, as for me is a little bit confusing

Comment: the library is a react datepicker and dropdowncomponent is a custom component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the value in redux and then use it accross siblings once the value is updated in redux on the change detection of the child you can use it across all the application

Comment: also you got the same name as mine i noticed

Comment: just want to know if it is the most efficient way to do this